# ubuntu firewall

Tags: networking, server, iptables, firewall

I am using ubuntu server as firewall with 3 interfaces (interface for students and another for teachers and DMZ) in VMware, I want  to block Facebook website for customers of `eth1` then I used this rule:

```
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP -p tcp --destination - port 443 -i eth1
```

But it did not work and the customers of interface `eth1` always access the site, how block sites for clients of `eth1` using rules `iptables` ?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook utilizes multiple Internet servers to handle incoming requests. So you need to reject multiple ip addresses.
[Here you can find the most common active IP addresses for Facebook.com](http://compnetworking.about.com/od/traceipaddresses/f/facebook-ip-address.htm).

---

To reject you can use with [UFW](https://launchpad.net/ufw). I recommend [GUFW](http://gufw.org/).
Example to reject using `ufw`:

```
ufw reject out to 31.13.64.0/18
ufw reject out to 66.220.144.0/20
ufw reset
```

Or you can work directly with `iptables`. Example to reject using `iptables`:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 31.13.64.0/18 -j REJECT
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 66.220.144.0/20 -j REJECT
```

---

Source: https://www.howtoforge.com/blocking-facebook-web-trackers-at-the-firewall-for-extra-privacy

Answer (score 0):

Edit the `/etc/hosts` file as `root` on the needed machine and add the following lines:

```
127.0.0.1 facebook.com login.facebook.com secure.facebook.com latest.facebook.com inyour.facebook.com beta.facebook.com static.facebook.com touch.facebook.com developers.facebook.com newsroom.fb.com pixel.facebook.com apps.facebook.com graph.facebook.com m.facebook.com upload.facebook.com
```

It will block the facebook access.